# Selecting a representative permutation

Tags: probability, permutations

If we have a complete set of permutations {m} = n choose k, how do I select a representative set of permutations in a stream such that the selected set say, {s} keeps growing to include permutations from {m} yet maintain it's representative nature to parent set {m}.  One way to look at this representative nature is to sort {s} and regress with original. Yes, though I've not been explicit, I'm interested to know the possibility of predicting a future sequence of a permutation from a partial set.

But here's my revised question:

Given permutations of a set, are there methods to determine which of the permutations will **appear** random? I read about statistical tests for randomness but most seem to be perspective based tests and I'm not sure which tests are reliable.

I say appear since the apparent nature of random size and order of elements in the representative sample seems really a conscious mental notion since human mind can't find an obvious pattern, and may be math as well.

Comment: If you draw randomly from your list (according to uniform distribution), why would that not be "representative" (whatever you mean by that)?

Comment: It seems to me that there may be an interesting question buried in here, but the OP unfortunately condensed the question too much. I am reluctant to vote to close this yet.

Comment: When I was looking at the representative sample of data, I overlooked that fact that I was looking at a sorted sample and not the original random sample. So out goes the curve fitting.

Answer (score 0):

**Appearing** random is in the eye of the beholder.  Everybody would find the permutation $1234\dots n$ non-random.  But if you picked a random permutation, it has chance $\frac 1{n!}$ of being chosen, just like any other.  How about the permutation $854917632?$  To any non-English speaker, and to many English speakers, it **appears** random.  But I constructed it by a simple rule, so it isn't random in my usage.